# Bind a boost signal with phoenix bind

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi, boost-phoenix, boost-signals

I am using boost spirit qi to parse inbound data then dispatch the correct functionality depending on it's content.

I am using `boost::signals` to manage the callbacks; my problem is that I don't seem to be able to use phoenix bind with the boost signals.

Consider the following test case:

```
 #include <boost/signals.hpp>

 #include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
 #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_bind.hpp>
 #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>

 #include <iostream>

 void f(int i) {
     std::cout << i << '\n';
 }

 int main() {
     boost::signal<void(int)> sig;

     sig.connect(f);

     std::string s="123";
     auto first=s.cbegin(), last=s.cend();    

     boost::spirit::qi::parse(
         first, last,
         (
             boost::spirit::qi::int_
             [
                 boost::phoenix::bind(sig, boost::spirit::qi::_1)
             ]
         )
     ); 
 }
```

This doesn't compile, spitting out a wall of errors.

Note that if I replace the phoenix bind line with

```
boost::phoenix::bind(&f, boost::spirit::qi::_1)
```

it works as expected (however due to the larger design of the program this isn't possible).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would compile if you'd change the above line to `                 boost::bind(boost::ref(sig), _1)
` (include the appropriate headers). However, for some reason I haven't managed to pass `sig` by ref with phoenix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted by Igor R. in the comments, your original error was due to the fact that `phoenix::bind` copies its arguments by default and `boost::signal`s are non-copyable. When you use `phoenix::ref` to solve that, another error emerges, this one caused by Boost.Phoenix v2's inability to find the returned type. This can also be easily solved by defining `BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3`.

```
 #include <boost/signals.hpp>

 #define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
 #include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
 #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_bind.hpp>
 #include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix_core.hpp>

 #include <iostream>

 void f(int i) {
     std::cout << i << '\n';
 }

 int main() {
     boost::signal<void(int)> sig;

     sig.connect(f);

     std::string s="123";
     auto first=s.cbegin(), last=s.cend();    

     boost::spirit::qi::parse(
         first, last,
         (
             boost::spirit::qi::int_
             [
                 boost::phoenix::bind(boost::phoenix::ref(sig), boost::spirit::qi::_1)
             ]
         )
     ); 
 }
```

Comment: +1 not saying anything :) (we have just been [discussing how on earth only 2 people still have the boost silver badge](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/9102711#9102711) to date...; I'll add "anonymous beneficiaries" to the list of contributing factors)

Comment: Ah, it's still v2 by default... I tried to put phoenix::bind<void> explicitly, but it didn't compile either.